# Pluralization of savings and costs (plural expressions of plural quantities)

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a list of savings, expressed in terms of the items that necessitate the original costs. For example, say that I have to purchase sewing material. My first question is: in expressing the amount of money required to obtain this material over the course of a year, should I say *Sewing Material Cost* or *Sewing Material Costs*?

In the act of purchasing material, there is a set *cost* per unit of product. However, when discussing the cumulative money spent on material in a year — the sum of multiple purchases — do you use the plural?

Now, I want to express the amount of money saved in my material purchasing expenses. I would say *Savings of Material Costs* (savings of material cost doesn't seem to make sense to me), which ultimately becomes *Material Costs Savings*. This, for some reason, seems weird to me.

Something resembling *material costs savings* is where I want to end up, but I'm not sure if my grammatical composition is correct.

Comment: There's a little bit of ambiguity in the word "material"; it can mean "tangible" or "real", so "material cost" can be interpreted as "real cost" as opposed to "projected cost".  (I do concede that most readers would only be confused for a second at most!)  Also, "material" is colloquially used as a substitute for "cloth", so "material cost" might be interpreted as cloth only, without thread, buttons, etc.  For both of these reasons, I would suggest the term **[materials cost](http://www.accountingformanagement.com/Manufacturing_and_nonmanufacturing_cost.htm#Direct%20Materials%20Cost)**.

Comment: I know that "material cost" is perfectly valid, and indeed [more commonly used](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=material+cost%2C+materials+cost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) - I just think that "materials cost" would be a (slightly) better choice here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Cost* is typically left without the `s` if there is only one purchase:

> The cost of thread

Using *costs* here would imply more than one type of cost:

> The costs of homeschooling

You can still say this without the `s` but the connotation shifts back to one solitary cost:

> The cost of homeschooling

It is ambiguous whether these costs are monetary or emotional or something else. Referring to bundles of purchases will typically use *costs*:

> Needle costs are rising
>
> These are my needle costs

If you used *cost* here it would shift back into a description of needle markets or a single project's purchase:

> Needle cost is rising
>
> This my needle cost

The differences between *cost* and *costs* in these examples are subtle and could be entirely regional. One final note is referring to how much something costs. This will follow standard pluralization rules:

> The book costs $4
>
> The books cost $4

To directly answer your question, I would use *costs*: **Sewing Material Costs**. Variations:

> Sewing Material Costs — the money spent on sewing material over multiple purchases
>
> Sewing Materials Cost — the amount required to buy "sewing materials"
>
> Sewing Materials Costs — the amount spend on sewing materials over multiple purchases

---

*Savings* is most typically plural in the sense that you are using it:

> Our savings on needles are significant
>
> These are my coupon savings
>
> I have $300 in savings

What you want to do is replace "coupon" in the second example with "Material Costs":

> Material Costs Savings — the savings on "material costs"

The use of "costs savings" is probably what makes this seem strange. The idea that you are accumulating savings through costs is counter-intuitive. But you aren't saving *through* costs, you are saving *on* costs. The alternatives are not quite what you are looking for:

> Material Cost Savings — the savings on the price of "material"
>
> Materials Cost Savings — the savings on the price of "materials"

These don't make much sense to me. I don't think "savings" works well with "cost".

> Materials Costs Savings — the savings on "materials costs"

This *works* but the extra plural is even more distracting. This form would work better with other objects, however:

> Needle Costs Savings
>
> Car Costs Savings

You can to try to use a hyphen to reduce the awkwardness:

> Material-Costs Savings

But I would just stick with **Material Costs Savings**.

Answer (score 2):

'Material costs savings' is perfectly valid, but it is also semantically dense. There is a lot of information in a few words. You might consider spacing it out a little to let it breathe. However, that depends on your purpose. To give an example of what I am talking about, you might say "total cost savings on all of the material purchases." This is a lot more words, but spaces out the meaning a little, and makes it easier to understand.

Regarding "sewing material cost" verses "sewing material costs"; both are correct, but have difference emphases. The first looks at the cost as a whole, the second looks at each of the costs individually. The "sewing material cost" might be "$250", the "sewing material costs" might be "$15 for silk, $25 for cotton, $5 for black thread" and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of line items that represent money you owe or must pay, those are "costs", related to whatever the topic of the list happens to be. A "cost" is just one of those things, or referred to in general as "the cost" ("cost" can be both a countable and uncountable noun in this regard). So, if you have line items for muslin, cotton duck, satin, etc. those are Sewing Material *Costs*.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with "Material cost savings" as a synonym for "savings in material costs".