# Is "Cost savings" a singular term or plural terms?

Tags: grammatical-number

Can I use *Cost savings* in the following sentence as a singular term?

> Cost savings is often seen with these program.

Comment: Related Questions: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/why-does-american-english-pluralize-certain-singular-nouns  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31095/pluralization-of-savings-and-costs-plural-expressions-of-plural-quantities

Comment: Unrelated to the specific point of your question, but I thought I'd mention it:  It should be *these programs* or *this program*.

Answer (score 1):

The word *savings*, like *clothes* or *thanks*, is a plural and must take a plural verb:

> His clothes **are** all over the bedroom floor.
>
> His savings **are** in a Swiss bank account.

I'm not overly familiar with the context and usage of the term *cost savings*, but I assume it conforms to this convention.

> Cost savings for this quarter **are** the largest we've had for years.

Contrast this with other nouns which may appear to be plural but are in fact singular, such as *athletics* or *mathematics*:

> Mathematics **is** my favourite subject.

Comment: I'll note that in American English, it's fairly common for *savings* to be treated as a singular noun.  *A savings of $20 is quite a lot*, etc.

Comment: @Dusty: Quite true, as noted in your links above. But you'll find very few instances of that usage being extended to [a cost savings](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+savings%2Ca+cost+savings&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Dusty, thanks, I admit to having heard that term used also (here in Australia). But I would say that 'savings' in that context is being used incorrectly; it should probably be '_A saving of $20 ..._'

Comment: @Snubian: *"A saving of $20 ..."* sounds much worse to this American than *"A savings of $20 ...";* To me, that's like fixing the bad grammar in *"buy a clothes"* by changing it to *"buy a cloth"*. I would recommend *"Savings of $20"*, keeping it plural and dropping the article. But even in American English, without any dollar amount, *"Cost savings"* should definitely be plural.

Comment: @PeterShor, I understand where you're coming from, but '_Savings of $20 is quite a lot_' sounds worst of all to me. I would say that the fact is ['saving' is singular and 'savings' is plural](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saving). This dictates the verb that follows. You could say _A saving of $20 is ..._ or _Savings of $20 are ..._

Comment: @Snubian: I would indeed recommend *"Savings of $20 are ..."*, not *"is"*. Sorry for not being clearer. But in American English, *"savings"* is generally used in the plural, and to me *"a saving"* sounds strange for that meaning (like *"a cloth"* sounds strange for *"an item of clothing"*).

Comment: @PeterShor, I appreciate your point, these regional differences develop, what sounds good to me might sound weird to you and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The word "savings" is singular or plural depending on what it's referring to.  If you are talking about savings for a single object, it is singular...  "The savings for this event IS...".   If the object is plural, then "savings" becomes plural...  "The savings experienced by those businesses ARE..."

Comment: No, What you mean is that *savings* like *dollars* can be construed as having a singular meaning. But "The savings for this one event were not enough" disproves your answer. As does "The savings experienced by those businesses is much more than expected."